# How to remove in node-telegram-bot-api only the bot.on() function?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

How can I just remove the bot.on () in order to rerun the bot.onText ()?
Because if I do bot.removeListener ('message') it also removes the bot.onText ()

```
       bot.onText(/\/login/, (msg) => {

                  bot.on('message', (msg) => {
                        //do some stuff
                        bot.removeListener('message');
                  });

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Second argument, should be a function of your listener.
F.e.:

```
let handler = (msg) => {
  let chatId = getChatId(msg);
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Login");
  bot.removeListener("message", handler);
};

bot.onText(/\/login/, msg => {
  bot.on("message", handler);

  bot.on("message", msg => {
    let chatId = getChatId(msg);
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Another listener");
  });
});
```

As you can see, the first time both listeners work, on the second attempt to enter something, only the second listener works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg7Aw.png)

Comment: Try to repeat the "/ login" command and both listeners will appear again.

Comment: it is still giving bot.removeListener is not a function error, maybe it is because of new version of API?